# Trying to locate a character in a two dimensional array with the row number and the column number in java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm not sure what to use in order to locate characters at a certain position in my two dimensional array. What I am trying to do is to have the user input the row and column number and fetch the value correspondant to those two variables in the two dimensional array, retrieve it and subsequently set it to 0 in the array

```
      import java.util.*;
public class twoDimension {
    public static void printRow(int[] row) {

        for (int i : row) {
            System.out.print(i);
            System.out.print("\t");
            }
        System.out.println();
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int twoDm[][]= new int[3][4];

        for (int i = 0; i < twoDm.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < twoDm[i].length; j++) {
                twoDm[i][j] = (int)(Math.random()*10); // we decided to randomise the numbers in the array.
                }
            }

        for(int[] row : twoDm) {
            printRow(row);
            }

        System.out.println("Enter a number with the format 'xy'. x is the row number and y the column number. Whenever you want to quit out, input 'quit'.");
        String xy;
        while (!xy.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            String xy = scanner.nextLine();
            char x = xy.charAt(0);
            char y = xy.charAt(1);
            // fetching the character in the array and displaying it
            // setting it to 0
            // displaying the array again 
            }
        }
    }
```

PS : I managed to find how I can display the array without commas or brackets, but am unsure about removing the spaces in the display.

Comment: By "the spaces in the display" do you mean the tabs created by `System.out.print("\t")`?

Comment: yes i do, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you turn the `x` and `y` coordinates to integers:

```
int xCoor = Character.getNumericValue(x);
int yCoor = Character.getNumericValue(y);
```

then you can access and/or modify the array by using those coordinates:

```
twoDm[xCoor][yCoor] = 0;
```

Comment: the compiler brings this up :                                                                     char cannot be converted to String
   int xCoor = Integer.parseInt(x);

Comment: @Dracose Sorry, I thought `x` and `y` were `String` values. I updated my answer to fix this.

Comment: @Dracose If this answer works, make sure to accept it to show the community it helped you.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a beginner haha

Comment: @Dracose No problem. Welcome to Stack Overflow!